# VB6.0 call a Sub written in a BAS Module from a Class Module CLS not working

Tags: dll, vb6, activex, com+, subroutine

I am writing VB6.0 projects (DLL with COM+) starting from previously written code.
I have a "main" Class Module CLS file with "main" Functions, and the Process flow etc.
I have also a "side" Module BAS where I save all the Functions / Subroutines to use as tools in my "main" Class Module.

I have written a very very straightforward logging system (because I feel very unconfortable with App.LogEvent("blablabla") ) but I am not able to compile the DLL. The message points me to the CLS call and I think the problem is related to the Sub that should return a value, but I do not want to return any value from that Sub!
I am quite new to VB6.0 and improving existing source code it is quite difficult.

Here is my Module BAS

```
Public Sub LogMyApp(ByVal sFunctionName As String, ByVal sLogEntry As String)

    Dim sLogPath As String
    sLogPath = "C:\Temp\MyLog.txt"

    Dim fn As Integer
    fn = FreeFile

    Open sLogPath For Append As #fn
    Write #fn, Now & "|" & sFunctionName & "|" & sLogEntry
    Close #fn

End Sub
```

Here is my Class Module CLS call to that Sub inside the BAS Module

```
LogMyApp ( "FunctionBlaBla" , "blablabla" )
```

Any help is really appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add the exact error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple fix, remove the parens as you are not calling a function;

```
LogMyApp "FunctionBlaBla" , "blablabla"
```

(Or as purely a visual thing prefix with the Call keyword; `call LogMyApp(...)`)

Comment: That fixed the problem! I was sure it was a really simple fix, I need to write much more VB6.0 lines cause I am a newby! Thanks!

Comment: +1 This is, of course, one of the classic [13 ways to have VB6](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/imhoinmyhumbleopinion/a/aaVerityStob1.htm)